# How to combine nth-child hover and before

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a paragraph that I would like to animate with hover, creating a border all around it.

So far, I know that nth-child is correctly defined, but I can't figure out a way to combine hover and before for all elements. It will only work with the first one (.spanniard span:hover::before) but the others do nothing.

Any ideas are welcome, including to solve the issue by attacking the @keyframe element and forgetting all about span:nth-child(n).

This is my HTML:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
     <head>
       <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./animate.css">
     </head>
     <body>
      <div class=spanniard>
       <p class=movement id="ache-uno" onmouseover="secularum()" 
          onmouseout="seculosa()">TEST</p>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <span></span>
       <p class=background id="background">BACKGROUND</p>
      </div>
     </body>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="animate.js"></script>
   </html>
```

And here is my CSS:

```
   .background {
     width: 300px;
     height: 50px;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
   }

   .background:hover::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     width: 250px;
     height: 50px;
     border-radius: 0.5rem;
     display: flex;
     top: 80px;
     align-items: flex-start;
   }

   span {
     position: absolute;
     width: 250px;
     height: 50px;
     border-radius: 0.5rem;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: flex-start;
   }

   .spanniard span:hover::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: 25px;
     width: 250px;
     height: 50px;
     border-radius: 0.5rem;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: flex-start;
     -webkit-animation-name: animatron;
     -moz-animation-name: animatron;
     animation-name: animatron;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
     animation-duration: 0.5s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   }

   .spanniard span:nth-child(2):hover::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: 25px;
     width: 250px;
     height: 50px;
     border-radius: 0.5rem;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: flex-start;
     -webkit-animation-name: animatron2;
     -moz-animation-name: animatron2;
     animation-name: animatron2;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 0.3s;
     -moz-animation-delay: 0.3s;
     animation-delay: 0.3s;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
     animation-duration: 0.5s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   }

   .spanniard span:nth-child(3):hover::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: 25px;
     width: 250px;
     height: 50px;
     border-radius: 0.5rem;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: flex-start;
     -webkit-animation-name: animatron3;
     -moz-animation-name: animatron3;
     animation-name: animatron3;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 0.6s;
     -moz-animation-delay: 0.6s;
     animation-delay: 0.6s;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
     animation-duration: 0.5s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   }

   .spanniard span:nth-child(4):hover::before {
     content: '';
     position: absolute;
     margin-left: 25px;
     width: 250px;
     height: 50px;
     border-radius: 0.5rem;
     display: flex;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: flex-start;
     -webkit-animation-name: animatron4;
     -moz-animation-name: animatron4;
     animation-name: animatron4;
     -webkit-animation-delay: 0.9s;
     -moz-animation-delay: 0.9s;
     animation-delay: 0.9s;
     -webkit-animation-duration: 0.5s;
     -moz-animation-duration: 0.5s;
     animation-duration: 0.5s;
     -webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     -moz-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
     animation-fill-mode: forwards;
   }

   @keyframes animatron {
     0% {background: blue; height: 2px; background-position: inherit;
         z-index: -1; display: flex; align-items: flex-start;
         transform: scale(0); transform-origin: left;}
     100% {background: blue; height: 2px; background-position: inherit;
          z-index: -1; display: flex; align-items: flex-start;
          transform: scale(1); transform-origin: left;}
   }

   @keyframes animatron2 {
     0% {background: blue; width: 2px; left: 256px; background-position:
         inherit; z-index: -1; display: flex; align-items: flex-start;
         transform: scale(0); transform-origin: top;}
     100% {background: blue; width: 2px; left: 256px; background-position: 
          inherit; z-index: -1; display: flex; align-items: flex-start; 
          transform: scale(1); transform-origin: top;}
   }

   @keyframes animatron3 {
     0% {background: red; height: 2px; top: 132px; background-position: 
          inherit; z-index: -1; display: flex; align-items: flex-end; 
          transform: scale(0); transform-origin: right;}
     100% {background: red; height: 2px; top: 132px; background-position: 
          inherit; z-index: -1; display: flex; align-items: flex-end; 
          transform: scale(1); transform-origin: right;}
   }

   @keyframes animatron4 {
     0% {background: red; width: 2px; left: 8px; background-position: 
          inherit; z-index: -1; display: flex; align-items: flex-end; 
          transform: scale(0); transform-origin: bottom;}
     100% {background: red; width: 2px; left: 8px; background-position: 
          inherit; z-index: -1; display: flex; align-items: flex-end; 
          transform: scale(1); transform-origin: bottom;}
   }
```

If I was to just animate without the hover and before pseudo class and element, like so:
.spanniard span
.spanniard span:nth-child(2)
.spanniard span:nth-child(3)
.spanniard span:nth-child(4)

It animates it perfectly, except for the fact that I need a hover, but hover won't work without before.

For this specific case, do you have an idea of how to make it work?

Comment: You example is far to complex.  You need to break it down into a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  For testing purposes you can remove all the transitions and transformations and just add an `outline 2px solid red` to see if the selector you've created works.

Comment: Not related to your question but note that `.spanniard span:hover` applies to all the children `span`.

Comment: In the example, what are you expecting? The four spans are in the same location on the screen, so you can only hover one of them.

Comment: I'm sorry that my example was hard to understand. What I was trying to do was to start an animation that surrounded the "BACKGROUND" text, starting top:0; left:0 of the <div>, moving 250px to the right (size of the element), then move down to the bottom 50px, from right to left 250px and bottom to top 50px using hover.
I mentioned that nth-child were properly defined, because they would do exactly that without the hover effect and I was looking for a way to add hover to that existing animation.
Thanks for your time looking at my code.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure it's what you're looking for but you can try for each span with 1 to 4

```
.spanniard:hover span:nth-of-type(1)::before {

}
```

Comment: You are brilliant!!!
I'm sorry that my example was hard to understand... The problem when you spend too many hours working on something and get frustrated.
What you tried, worked.

Comment: It's ok, happy I could help!